# Alignment issues in achievements dialog on non-responsive pages when viewed on mobile

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog

When viewing the achievements dialog on non-responsive pages (like the [review queue detail pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close)) in Safari on an iPhone, the alignment is off: reputation changes take more horizontal space than badges. Also, the badges align to the bottom of the row instead of the top.

[image]

<sub>I am not sure if all pages will eventually get the responsive treatment; if they do, it's probably not worth the effort to solve it.</sub>