# Spacing of achievements dropdown from /review on mobile site is "wonky"

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

Prompted by the discussion in chat starting [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50994971#50994971), especially [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50995124#50995124) about the spacing being "wonky".

The padding of badge icons in achievements dropdown is off when viewing from mobile. [Review pages aren't responsive yet](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50995090#50995090) (on mobile view, they look like a mix of full site/regular mobile view), but "even if the page isn't responsive, the padding between the items should be fine" ([transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50995156#50995156)).

Screenshot below, on Chrome 74.0 (reproduced on Chrome 75.0), Android 5.1.1. No userscripts, or at least none that I willingly installed.

[image: Broken padding on Achievements dropdown]

Apparently there's [no repro on Catija's iPhone](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50995111#50995111).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alignment issues in achievements dialog on non-responsive pages when viewed on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323731/alignment-issues-in-achievements-dialog-on-non-responsive-pages-when-viewed-on-m) - I'm still experiencing it on my iPhone.

Comment: @Glorfindel Weird... but it works fine on my iPhone... I guess it's the old version of Safari I have... Hmmm.

Comment: Could be. I have an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 12.3.1.

Comment: I think I'm on a 6S running *cough* 10.2.1 *cough*...

Comment: It happens on my iPhone 7, which is one update behind. Oddly, **if viewing the desktop version, the achievements work even though it’s not responsive.**